# IonCube with magento Modules

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, ioncube

Is anyone got to tried out the ionCube with magento modules before distributing it. Unfortunately i couldnot ended up well, so i am looking for someone who can solve this.

I did these one by one.

1. made simple module to say Hello world. So i have a set of folders into **app** in the **namespace** of **Mymodule** and module name called **Helloworld**,
2. So the as you guess the respected files are goes into local , etc/modules frontend/design/default . And the file types are here .php,.phtml, .xml,.csv(locale file), its all working well without encoding it with ioncube in magento 1.4.2
3. Now i installed the latest trail version of ioncube  in windows 7 and made a new project, added the **Mymodule** project into the project and followed everything well with the instructions. Ommited .xml,.csv files from encoding and only encoded the .php,.phtml files.
4. Now when i place the newly encoded module into the mage root i got fatl error of missing class files because magento not able to load the encoded file. My hosting provider told that they have upgraded version of ionCube.

I couldnot find out where am making mistake or what am missing here. I want to have a module which is encoded with the ioncube. Thats the goal. Did anybody tried this.

And to be specific am getting these sort of errors when i change the encoding version from php 5.5 to 5 in ioncube encoder.

**Fatal error:**
**The encoded file test/app/code/local/Mymodule/Helloworld/Model/Observer.php has expired. in Unknown on line 0**

Thanks
Ela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can encode only php files and you have to make sure that the licence file is in the same directory (if compilation is used then also in compilation directory) where compiled files are

but be warned that this ruins the debugging of magento and you can't or your clients can't no longer use debuggers in their development cycle. Chances are small that somebody ever will want to purchase your encoded extension as it needs more server setup and knowledge from the user who's buying this and if the user has that knowledge he most likely will choose open-sourced alternatives

Comment: Hi, thanks for your view on encoded open source. But i have to give it to the client who wants it in encoded format. I will try with license file. I forget that. thanks Anton